Show $\int_{0}^{1} \theta ^k (1- \theta)^l d \theta= \frac{\Gamma(k+1) \Gamma(l+1)}{\Gamma(k+l+2)}$ (Mixture of Bernoulli dists)
To prove this $\int_{0}^{1} \theta ^k (1- \theta)^l d\theta = \frac{\Gamma(k+1) \Gamma(l+1)}{\Gamma(k+l+2)}$ (for $k,l > -1$) I know you can use the definition of the Beta distribution - however I was given the hint/approach to multiply both sides by $ze^{-z}z^{k+l}$ and integrate from $0$ to $\infty$ $dz$. Which effectively reduces it to proving:
$$
\int_0^1 \int_0^{\infty} \theta^k(1-\theta)^lze^{-z}z^{k+l} dz d\theta = \Gamma(k+1) \Gamma(l+1)
$$
So I want to basically factorise the integral into two separate gamma integrals. Trying to induce Gamma densities into the integral I get:
$$\int_0^1 \frac{\Gamma(k+1)\Gamma(l+1)}{\theta(1-\theta)}\int_0^\infty z [\frac{\theta^{k+1} z^{k+1-1}e^{-\theta z}}{\Gamma(k+1)}][\frac{(1-\theta)^{l+1}z^{l+1-1}e^{-(1-\theta)z}}{\Gamma(l+1)}]dz d\theta$$
The two terms in the brackets being respective $f \sim Gamma(k+1, \theta), g \sim Gamma(l+1, 1-\theta)$ densities. However I am unsure on how to proceed - the inner integral looks like an expectation $E_f[Zg(Z)] = E_g[Zf(Z)]$ or some kind of convolution integral.
Any ideas on where to go from here - without abusing the Beta distribution and ideally only using the definition of the Gamma integral.

If you are aware of change of variables in dimension greater than one you can procede as follows. We go from the integral $$\int_0^1 \mathrm{d} \theta \int_0^\infty\mathrm{d} z ~\theta^k(1-\theta)^l e^{-z}z^{k+l+1} = \int_0^1 \mathrm{d} \theta \int_0^\infty\mathrm{d} z ~(\theta z)^k((1-\theta)z)^l e^{-z}z.$$ The idea is to regroup two terms which look like $u^k$ and $v^l$, here with $u=\theta z$ and $v= (1-\theta)z$. We use the change of variable implied by $f(\theta,z)= (\theta z,(1-\theta)z) = (u,v)$, the jacobian of $f(\theta,z)$ is $\begin{bmatrix}
z & \theta \\
-z &  1-\theta
\end{bmatrix}$, of which the determinant is $z.$ Notice also that $u+v =z$. The last integral equals to $$\int_0^\infty\int_0^\infty\mathrm{d}u\mathrm{d}v~v^k u^l e^{-(u+v)} = \Gamma(k+1)\Gamma(l+1).$$

Yeah this makes sense, cheers - didn't expect to have to use jacobian, thought there might be a trick
